# Can't change users within system() in php

Tags: php, permissions, sudo

My command is

```
echo root_password | sudo -u root -S executable_full_path arguments
```

The error message I get in the browser is

> [sudo] password for www-data: Sorry,
>   try again.

From phpinfo(), safe mode is off and there are no disabled functions.  Why isn't this working?  The same command runs fine in the shell (bash).  Escapeshellarg and escapeshellcmd don't make a difference.

EDIT: Simply being able to execute the command is not enough.  The program that gets executed creates a socket in /tmp, and needs to assign it permissions.  So I think I really need to be root for this, is that possible?

Comment: What's the IP of your system. I'd love to just sit on a shell and watch 'top'. The root password should flash by any time now...

Comment: @Marc I just did that, ran the script, and saw no such thing.  Sorry bro, could have been funny.

Comment: @Marc: It's being injected via stdin, not the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Álvaro suggested, I'm putting my comment as answer. Matt, this would make it possible to run that command as root.

@Matt, don't do that `/etc/sudoers` (btw, you edit this file with the `visudo` command, never directly). That way you are making possible that any `sudo whatever` command run by your web application is run by root, possibiliting a lot of fun for an attacker if he founds a vulnerability in your application.

If you would like to run just ONE command as root without need for passwords, put this in `/etc/sudoers` (remember `visudo` command):

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: executable_full_path
```

Then you are only allowing to execute just this command as root. Now you should be able to do

```
sudo -u root executable_full_path arguments
```

without need to type in a password (and it will run as root). Also, this is the only command the user www-data may execute as root using sudo, so it should not be dangerous.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't quite put the pieces together correctly before, this did it.  Thank you--

Comment: Hello I have daemon issue. My python script is fine in terminal but failed in symfony framewrok. Please help me

Answer (score 3):

You're echoing the root password when you should be echoing the password for `www-data`.

Comment: @Ignacio Really?  I don't understand that, but oh well.  Googling indicates that adding www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL to /etc/sudoers will solve this, is there a better way?  I don't know if I necessarily want everything owned by www-data to have root privileges, which is what it looks like this does.

Comment: @Ignacio How do I do that?  Sorry I'm just breaking in to this sort of thing.  I haven't been able to get the first solution to work yet anyway.

Comment: @Matt, don't do that `/etc/sudoers` (btw, you edit this file with the `visudo` command, never directly). That way you are making possible that any `sudo whatever` command run by your web application is run by `root`, possibiliting a lot of fun for an attacker if he founds a vulnerability in your application. If you would like to run just ONE command as root without need for passwords, put this in `/etc/sudoers` (remember `visudo` command): `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: executable_full_path`. Then you are only allowing to execute just this command as root.

Comment: @Carlos: you seem to have provided the right answer but it's a comment and it cannot be tagged as accepted. I suggest you copy your information into a proper answer.

Comment: @Alvaro Carlos has provided a helpful answer which in many cases would be good enough, but not mine unfortunately, see my edit.

Comment: @Carlos Actually I did this and now the script is hanging on the call to the executable (no sudo anymore, and the executable is 0777).  The same command runs fine from the shell (?!)  Also your answer as it is probably won't work for me, see my edit

Comment: @Matt you should put `sudo` in front of the command, otherwise it won't get executed as root. Also, no need to 0777 the executable, better leave it with 0755.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on your /ets/sudoers
Example for run gconftool-2 :

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/gconftool-2
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/sudo
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```